# Is there a way to imitate aws api gateway mock reponse on GCP api-gateway?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, swagger-2.0, api-gateway, google-api-gateway

Im trying to implement a /health endpoint which will only return 200 on gcp (mock). on my aws api gateway theres Mock integration, which makes things simple.

Ive tried to deploy an api gateway with this swagger

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: some API
paths:
  /test:
    get:
      operationId: test
      summary: testapi
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response
```

and its valid using https://editor.swagger.io/ , furthermore ur im managing to deploy it but testing results in

```
{"message":"no healthy upstream","code":503}
```

What im missing? Couldnt find anything on documentation https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/creating-api-config

Answer (score 0):

There's no feature right now from Google Cloud to mock an AWS API Gateway resonse to GCP API Gateway. However, this workaround might help:

1. Create a backend service that always returns a 200 OK response.
2. Configure API Gateway to route requests to your backend service for the `/health` endpoint.
3. Deploy your API and test it by making a GET request to the `/health` endpoint.

This will allow you to test your API without having to rely on a real backend service.

Documentation Reference that might help you:

- [GCP API Gateway Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs)
- [Creating Mock Backends for API Gateway](https://chetan07.medium.com/how-to-mock-googleauth-of-googleapis-b0988475c6b4)

You may also file a feature request in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).